# Infinite line charge - why dependent on $r$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, coulombs-law

For an infinite line charge, the Electric field at a point depends on $r$. While I understand the proof of this by Gauss’s law, with intuition, not so much.

The explanation people go by is the more you move from line, the $E$ weakens inversely by square law but at the same time, we see a bigger angular cone (bigger segment of line) by $r$.

**Why is it that when we move further away, we focus on the explanation that we see bigger line? Even if we stayed close, it is true our view would see smaller line, but the effect of infinite charges from the infinity line would still have the same effect. Whats going on here?**

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide an answer using the dimensionality of the problem. Gauss' Law says that the total electric field over a surface is constant provided the charge contained is the same. This means roughly

$$ EA \sim Q \tag{1}$$

i.e the flux is governed by the total charge inside the surface. Now, consider a point particle in d-dimensions and consider a surface defined by some length r. Since volume scales like $V \sim r^d$ in d dimensions, surface area will scale as $A \sim r^{d-1}$. Then equation ($1$) becomes

$$ E \sim 1/r^{d-1} \tag{2}$$

where I neglected the dependence on the charge. Now consider the scenario you are asking: an infinitely long charged wire. It is crucial to notice that from the perspective of the wire, there are only $\textbf{2}$ dimensions: you can either move away from the wire or rotate around it. If you move along the wire, it doesn't change anything. So the infinite wire problem in $d=3$ is the same problem as a point charge in $d=2$. Therefore, using our formula, we find that the electric field scales like

$$ E \sim 1/r $$

This argument gives you the correct scaling for the electric field! We can go a little further and consider an infinite sheet in $d=3$. Now using the same line of reasoning, the only "relevant" direction according to the sheet is radial direction away from it. Therefore, an infinite charged sheet in $d=3$ is equivalent to a point-like particle in $d=1$. Then our formula says that the electric field scales like

$$ E \sim r^0 $$

which is the correct scaling when we use the appropriate machinery! The crux of the problem lies in the dimensionality of the system!

Answer (score 0):

The effect you're missing is the cancellation of horizontal components of the E field vectors. When you're closer to the line, the charges that are farther away are not only weaker; they are also more horizontal so that they cancel with charges from the other side.